# Probabilistic proof for expander existence

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, expander-graphs, existence-theorems

I am new to probabilistic proofs and trying to understand them better. Apparently, a common probabilistic proof focuses on the existence of expanders (eg. vertex expanders).
I've been using the search tool and google a lot but either I can't find such a proof or I didn't recognize it as such.

Could anyone please explain the proof as simple as possible or refer to a good reference?